# AD B2C MSAL integration for Android fails upon profile policy cancellation in Spanish

Tags: android, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

This issue applies to the scenario using AD B2C edit profile and recover password policies in conjunction with the Android MSAL library (com.microsoft.identity.client:msal-0.1.1).

When using languages containing special characters (like French or Spanish), if the user selects the “Cancel” button on either the password recovery or edit profile policies the application aborts due to a URL decode error.  AD B2C sends back a standard user cancel error with code AADB2C90091 (which isn’t really an error and is expected).  However, in the case of French/Spanish, there are Unicode characters in the URL that represent accent marks, etc. that cannot be decoded.

This appears to be a bug in the Android MSAL library but does anyone have a solution (beyond changing the error message description to remove the special characters)?

Error Message for Spanish:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid % sequence at 50: AADB2C90091:+El+usuario+ha+cancelado+la+introducci%u00f3n+de+informaci%u00f3n+afirmada+por+%u00e9l+mismo.
              Correlation+ID:+c413b66a-4a69-43d2-8a3c-6111cea7f1b0
              Timestamp:+2018-01-28+20:33:39Z

                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4067)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4110)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:177)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1498)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5953)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid % sequence at 50: AADB2C90091:+El+usuario+ha+cancelado+la+introducci%u00f3n+de+informaci%u00f3n+afirmada+por+%u00e9l+mismo.
              Correlation+ID:+c413b66a-4a69-43d2-8a3c-6111cea7f1b0
              Timestamp:+2018-01-28+20:33:39Z

                  at libcore.net.UriCodec.decode(UriCodec.java:169)
                  at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(URLDecoder.java:60)
                  at com.microsoft.identity.client.MsalUtils.urlFormDecode(MsalUtils.java:127)
                  at com.microsoft.identity.client.MsalUtils.decodeUrlToMap(MsalUtils.java:298)
                  at com.microsoft.identity.client.AuthorizationResult.parseAuthorizationResponse(AuthorizationResult.java:94)
                  at com.microsoft.identity.client.AuthorizationResult.create(AuthorizationResult.java:72)
                  at com.microsoft.identity.client.InteractiveRequest.onActivityResult(InteractiveRequest.java:157)
                  at com.microsoft.identity.client.PublicClientApplication.handleInteractiveRequestRedirect(PublicClientApplication.java:313)
                  at com.tekmar.msal.TekmarMSAL.onActivityResult(TekmarMSAL.java:200)
                  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterfaceImpl.onActivityResult(CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:152)
                  at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.onActivityResult(CordovaActivity.java:358)
                  at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6549)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4063)
```

Comment: Issue created here: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/253